# Smart contract events are being emitted multiple times with exactly the same data using Ethers JS

Tags: ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets, typescript

Please someone help me here.

I am trying to read events to update the state of the data to make my dapp but the problem I am facing is on a function call, the same event is emitted multiple times (16 to 40 times). I need to limit this to only one so I can update my state only once. I am using Ethers Js with typescript.

You can also have a look at my code.

[image]

Comment: is that your component rendering multiple times? I am facing the same issue but it happens only two times since my component is rendering two times. I am trying to find a better way to do this.

Comment: You are correct. The problem was component rendering multiple times. I solved my problem by packing event code inside useEffect hook.

Comment: This is my exact code which is working perfectly. [Code](https://i.ibb.co/2Wc8NBg/Untitled.png)